# Complex of abelian groups not quasi-isomorphic to its own cohomology

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-groups

One can show that if $\mathcal{A}$ is an abelian category of homological dimension $\leqq 1$ (say, abelian groups for simplicity) then any object in the bounded derived category $\mathcal{D}^b(\mathcal{A})$ splits as its cohomology groups, that is, if $X \in \mathcal{D}^b(\mathcal{A})$, and
$$
H(X) = \bigoplus_n H^n(X)
$$
with zero differentials seen as an object in $\mathcal{D}^b(\mathcal{A})$, then $X \simeq H(X)$ are quasi-isomorphic.

I know this cannot hold for the unbounded version of this, because it is well known that if every object in $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{A})$ splits as the sum of its cohomologies then $\mathcal{A}$ is semisimple. However, I have failed to write down a complex (say of abelian groups) which is non-split!

Silly question maybe, but can someone write down an explicit complex of abelian groups that does not split as the sum of its cohomologies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, the unbounded version does hold. There is a proof in Section 1.6 of

*Krause, Henning*, [**Derived categories, resolutions, and Brown representability**](http://www.arxiv.org/abs/math/0511047), Avramov, Luchezar L. (ed.) et al., Interactions between homotopy theory and algebra. Summer school, University of Chicago, IL, USA, July 26–August 6, 2004. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 978-0-8218-3814-3/pbk). Contemporary Mathematics 436, 101-139 (2007). [ZBL1132.18005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1132.18005).

It *is* true that every object of the *homotopy* category $\mathcal{K}(\mathcal{A})$ is the direct sum of its homology objects if and only if all short exact sequences in $\mathcal{A}$ split (I write that rather than "$\mathcal{A}$ is semisimple" because there is more than one definition of a semisimple abelian category: see [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327899/name-for-abelian-category-in-which-every-short-exact-sequence-splits) for a discussion).

Comment: This is very interesting! My claim about D(A) rather then K(A) actually came from Gelfand and Manin's book "Methods of homological algebra" (see III.2.3 and III.2.4) which I imagine is incorrect then (the proof of the result i claimed is an exercise)

I will accept your answer as soon as I understand this reference you sent me